# Sending Exceptions over WCF w/ Kerberos - Retrieving exception detail tripping up auth request

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, kerberos

I've set up a WCF service, which is intended to run under Kerberos. The issue I'm having is that whenever I throw an exception from the service to the client, it appears to be making a separate request for the exception detail, and failing with **'The requirement for mutual authentication was not met by the remote server.'**.

The good news - Requests to service calls that don't throw exceptions work fine.

My current fallback is to allow NTLM, which I'd like to remove. I'd like to understand the heart of the issue, trying overcome the 'Kerberos is always difficult' mindset.

Basic network details:

- SPNs are registered for the service, against the NetBios + FQDN
  names, and the App Pool's service account. (Falling back to an http
  machine SPN is not available to us
- Anonymous is disabled

Exception types tried:

- Re-throwing original exception (Client has access to basic Exception
  types)
- [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx), (though I don't need custom exceptions, which it may be intended for)+ adding the following to each webservice method:

  [FaultContract(typeof(FaultException))]

### Client-side detail

**Setting the ClientCredential**: (Client)

```
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
credentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = false; // Set to true to allow it to work;
credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
```

**Other fixes from previous issues:**

*SpnEndpointIdentity* set, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914699/wcf-why-does-passing-in-a-remote-endpoint-fail)

```
SpnEndpointIdentity spnEndpointIdentity = new SpnEndpointIdentity("");
var address = new EndpointAddress(EndpointName, spnEndpointIdentity)
```

To stop the *407 proxy error*:

```
BasicHttpBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
```

**The exception received by the client:** (Abbreviated stack trace)

(It appears to show that the *ProcessGetResponseWebException* call is trying to retrieve the  exception detail)

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled
  Message=An error (The request was canceled) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel.
  StackTrace:
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at Project.IMetadataManagement.GetMetadata(String identifier)
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       InnerException: System.Net.ProtocolViolationException
            Message=The requirement for mutual authentication was not met by the remote server.
```

---

### Server side detail

In the web config:

*includeExceptionDetailInFaults* is true

```
<behavior name="Project.MetadataBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
```

**Bindings:**

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Windows auth settings**

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="true" useAppPoolCredentials="true" >
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add value="Negotiate" />
            <add value="NTLM" />
          </providers>
          <extendedProtection tokenChecking="None" />
        </windowsAuthentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

**Service example**

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Project.MetadataBehavior" name="Project.MetadataManagement">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" contract="Project.IMetadataManagement">
        </endpoint>
</service>
```

Any and all help appreciated. I've blanked over the actual project namespaces, so hopefully I haven't left any clumsy mis-alignment.

Thanks.